# Migrations Are Not Taking Effect (Django - Python)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, class, schema

I think I have followed the correct process for getting migrations to work but the changes have not seem to have taken effect. I am trying to add a slug field to my Comments class `field=models.SlugField(blank=True, max_length=500)`.

**Schema**

```
sqlite> .schema blog_Comment
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "blog_comment" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "name" varchar(80) NOT NULL, "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL, "body" text NOT NULL, "created_on" datetime NOT NULL, "active" bool NOT NULL, "post_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "blog_post" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
CREATE INDEX "blog_comment_post_id_580e96ef" ON "blog_comment" ("post_id");
sqlite>
```

**0017_auto_20200426_2137.py**

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.6 on 2020-04-26 14:37

import datetime
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.utils.timezone import utc


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('blog', '0016_auto_20200426_0209'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='created_on',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 26, 14, 37, 27, 23071, tzinfo=utc)),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='comment',
            name='url',
            field=models.SlugField(blank=True, max_length=500),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='post',
            name='date_posted',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 26, 14, 37, 27, 23071, tzinfo=utc)),
        ),
    ]
```

**class Comment(models.Model):**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on= models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    url= models.SlugField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

Comment: what is output from `./manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

In your model, try

```
class Meta:
   managed=True
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting loads of old migration files from the last 6 weeks. Then making the migrations again. It now works.